# Android - Why after creating new objects it says "cannot be resolved or not a field"?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-juno

I'm very new to Android developing. 
When I create a new project and try to simply add a button using the graphical layout and try refering to it it won't find it.

Sometimes doing a "Clean..." works sometimes it doesn't. Also sometimes restarting eclipse works and sometimes it doesn't.

Is eclipse really that unstable or am I doing something wrong?

Also I should mention that I did go over all the posts of other people (I know this question is being asked alot) but I still haven't found an asnwer

Here is the .java file:

```
 package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.testapp.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }

}
```

and here is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: out telepaths are on vacation and we simply do not know what tools you are using.

Comment: Paste your code at which you have this error.

Comment: As @hardikjoshi wrote, let us see some code.

Comment: Also, do you get the same problem if you use another IDE? - If you do, then the IDE is not the problem ;-)

Comment: Im using Eclipse Juno. Can you recommend anything better?

Comment: Remove this line `import com.example.testapp.R;`

Comment: Hi Asok, I tried that. Didn't work :\

Comment: remove tools:context=".MainActivity"

Comment: After removing did you run "clean project" again? Sometimes cleaning the project will add this line back.

Comment: Yes after removing the line you mentioned I tried cleaning again

Comment: Okay... did it re-add the line? If so, remove the line again, save the file, then click "Run". That's assuming you have the project set to Automatically Build, which should be the default setting. Shouldn't need to Clean the project as you develop.

Comment: Ok so that worked... First of all thanks alot! So your'e saying that even if Eclipse shows me errors it may still run?

Comment: It will only run your application on warnings, not errors

Comment: You have to save your files for it to work